# how to set colorbar ticks to outside

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I want to set the ticks of the imshow colorbar outside, I know how to do it to the ticks of the axes, but I do not manage to do it to the ticks of the color bar of the histogram.

This is how to make the ticks pointing outside in the axes

```
tick_params(axis='y', direction='out')
tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')
```

how do I do it for the colorbar?

Tahnks

Comment: @ChrisWhite I wrote in the comment that there is an answer for this question, I did not delete it because it might be good for the search result.

Comment: The above is an auto-generated comment from putting the question in the duplicate review. There's no need to delete. The way the site works is exact duplicates are "closed as duplicate" (if enough high-rep users/moderators agree) with a link to the original question. This avoids having multiple identical threads spread across the site.